# Few items when searching with FIND_IN_SET MySql function

Tags: mysql

MySql `FIND_IN_SET` search takes first argument like one string.

But what if I have few variables to looking for in set?

```
 SET field {set_field} can be => 1,2 OR 1,3 OR 1,2,3 OR 2,3
```

Arguments for `search => array('1','2','3')`

And I dont wanna write condition like this:

```
FIND_IN_SET('1',{set_field}) OR FIND_IN_SET('2',{set_field}) OR FIND_IN_SET('3',{set_field})
```

Is there any other options?

Comment: try removing single quotes...

Comment: I am not saying it not working like I wrote before, I am trying to find other option, more compact, cause if i will have 40 agrs for search I will have 40 times of FIND_IN_SET conditions! Maybe there is exist some other option or function to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can load the values into a temp table and do a JOIN based on the FIND_IN_SET.

But not sure it is a real advantage

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE fred
(
    ID  INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

INSERT INTO fred VALUES (1),(2),(3);

SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN fred b
ON FIND_IN_SET(b.ID, a.set_field);
```